# Epicor and Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, epicorerp

I have a connection setup to OLE DB (ADO), I try to use integrated security but in Epicor it asks for a username and password to preview the report.  This only happens when I am pulling a table or a view from the SQL server that has the database.  So, I tried to do an ODBC connection, now it says in Epicor that it cannot connect to the database.  How do I use the OLE DB connection but not have it prompt for credentials in Epicor?

Answer (score 0):

You need a report viewer, which is able to preserve the login information.
Here are links to 2 free viewers:

http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/FreeCrystalReportsViewer.aspx

http://www.groffautomation.com